# reason of android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler error

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

There is an **old** source needs an update, but it shows an **Error**:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler
```

gradle.properties file included:

`android.useAndroidX = true`

`android.enableJetifier = false`

**app.gradle**:

`compileSdkVersion 29`
`minSdkVersion 19`
`targetSdkVersion 29`

```
def component_version = '27.1.1'
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + component_version
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:' + component_version
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:' + component_version
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:' + component_version
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    // FCM
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    // Material Dialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    // Yoyo Animation
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    // Abring SDK
    implementation 'com.github.msddev:abring-sdk-android:v0.4'
    // Infinite Scroll
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:infinitescroll:0.0.1'
    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    // JW player
    implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+'
    implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+'
    implementation project(':mediapicker')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to what you have included in your question, you are trying to add AndroidX libraries into your project.

Irregardless, the `android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat` which is an older support library is being referenced from multiple dependencies. That is the meaning of the error you are seeing.

To resolve this, you should run `gradlew app:dependencies` to retrieve a list of all libraries and see which is referencing the library in question.

Once you find the problem, you can exclude the library from the dependency by:

```
implementation ('library_name') {
       exclude module: 'android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat'
 }
```

I would also consult the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4-media/MediaBrowserCompat.CustomActionCallback) to migrate to AndroidX, since there is no more support for older support libraries.